# How to insert a user in the database only if there is no email address using the zend framework?

Tags: validation, zend-framework, email

I have my controller, my function to insert into the database, and the form.
I just want to insert the user in the database if he enter the email is not already registered in the database.

My controller:

```
$nome       = $this->_request->getParam('nome');
$senha      = $this->_request->getParam('senha');
$confirmar  = $this->_request->getParam('confirmar');
$email      = $this->_request->getParam('email');
$usuarios = new Application_Model_DbTable_Usuarios();
$usuarios->addUsuario($nome, $senha, $email);
```

My DbTable_Usuario class that contains my function that inserts the user in the database

```
public function addUsuario($nome, $senha, $email) {
    $data = array(
        'id'    =>  'NULL',
        'nome'  =>  $nome,
        'senha' =>  $senha,
        'email' =>  $email,
        'nivel' =>  '0'
    );
    $this->insert($data);
}
```

And my zend_form

```
$email = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('email');
    $email->setLabel('Email:')
          ->setRequired(true)
          ->addValidator('EmailAddress')
          ->addValidator('NotEmpty');
```

I have some way to add something to the form it checks if the mail entered already exists in the database? If it exists, it displays the message, and if not, insert it in the bank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.Db) validator to the email field.

Answer (score 0):

To give a closer insight on a specific problem using NoRecordExists. The Validator is added just at the way that other validators are

```
$email->addValidator('Db_NoRecordExists', false, array('table'=>'usario', 'field'=>'email'));
```

Depending on your form setup, you will use the exact same field for EDITING a user, too. When editing a user the NoRecordExists is a little tricky. As for once, you shouldn't be allowed to change into an existing email, but you should be able to update your other data and keep your email (which though is existing in your db in the current row).

You therefore need to remove the current row from that rule. There are several approaches, which you can see from [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832820/best-approach-on-exlcuding-fields-from-a-validator), but i think the following works best from controller level:

```
$form = new UserForm();
$form->getElement('email')->getValidator('Db_NoRecordExists')->setExclude(array(
  'field' => 'id',
  'value' => $idToEdit
))
```

Comment: I usually just call `->removeValidator('Db_NoRecordExists')` when I want to update.

Comment: @RockyFord Which is a bad thing - a user would be able to change his email (as an example) into an email of a different user - therefore you will have two users with the same email. Just exclude the current row from the validator.

Comment: I see your point, it's probably a good thing I don't use emails as a unique identifier. I will however keep it in mind.